# How to get url params in NextJS App router Layout Server component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to pass something like `?print=true` to a url in order to rearrange some elements (such as hiding header and main menu) for printable versions. I'm aware of the patterns to get request params from a `Page`, from a `Client Component` or even from the old `Page Router` system, but can't find a straight forward way to get url params from the `Layout`, which is where I have my common stuff to hide.

Any idea pointing in the right direction?

**EDIT**

According to the docs:

> Layouts
> Unlike Pages, Layouts (Server Components) do not receive the searchParams prop. This is because a shared layout is not re-rendered during navigation which could lead to stale searchParams between navigations. View detailed explanation.

> Instead, use the Page searchParams prop or the useSearchParams hook in a Client Component, which is re-rendered on the client with the latest searchParams.

So it seems the logic conclussion is *there's no way to achieve this*. Still, I would appreciate any feasable workaround.

Comment: If you only need to change some styles, you may use `@media print` in your CSS. Also you probably could add a class like `.print` to your `html` or `body` when you add the `print` search param and use the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) in CSS.

Comment: Mm I would have liked to avoid messing directly with CSS as I'm using `Tailwind`, but it's an interesting approach, thank you!

Comment: I think you can use [print styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#print-styles) in tailwind.